# Redirect 301 htaccess is using previous changes I made of it

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, xampp, http-status-code-301

This is my htaccess

```
Options All -Indexes
ErrorDocument 404 http://localhost/proyecto-dwes-main2/errors/404.php
Redirect 301 /proyecto-dwes-main2/index.php http://localhost/proyecto-dwes-main2/errors/underConstruction.php
```

The syntax of redirect is: Redirect 301 /oldpage/ /newpage/
Before the actual version of my htaccess, I tested the /oldpage with other files of my project. Now is redirecting all the files I tested with it previously, plus the actual /oldpage of the htaccess.
I am using xampp.

I have tried to restart the apache service but it doesnt work. I have no idea what is happening

Comment: Could it be that you are simply looking at _client side_ cached redirection results? Keep in mind that a 301 redirection specifically asked for the redirection to be _cached_ by the client to _prevent_ additional requests. Have a try and test again using a fresh. anonymous/inkognito browser window.

Comment: Yes, it was the cache, I used anonymous browser and it works properly. Thank you so much for your help, I was completly lost

Comment: FYI: Specifying an _absolute_ URL for ErrorDocument 404 is not a good idea; this will cause a _redirect_ to that URL, so that bots etc. won't get a proper 404 status code for the originally requested URL any more.

Comment: I tried using the path of the file and it doesnt work,; The errors folder which contains the 404.php file its on the same level as index.php. I tried with with /errors/404.php and other different paths and It doesnt work.

Comment: I have resolved the problem with redirect 404 using the correct path. I started the path by the name of the parent folder -> /Proyecto-DWES-Main2/errors/404.php